USB 3 slow speed: ~8 mb/s
I have a Z390 ASUS Maximus XI Hero with 3.1 USB support and a Toshiba KIOXIA TransMemory U366 USB Flash Drive 32GB USB3.2 Flash advertised with 100 MB/s.
Yet when I copy anything, I end up with this speed. Any idea why?


100MB/s read speed. Most usb keys have absolutely awful write speeds.

What exactly is your question? You have a USB 3.0 device connected to a USB 3.0 port. 600 Megabits per second is 75 Megabytes per second and only exist in a perfect environment. You have older hardware running on a slower USB specification

Check the images people have posted in amazon reviews: https://www.amazon.co.uk/KIOXIA-TransMemory-Flash-Drive-Transfer/dp/B09J3WH448#review-media-gallery_1713484357442 130MB/s read speed, 16MB/s write speed. Marketing people will generally only tell you the best figure you can expect and that's when reading from the drive, the actual write speeds are often only a fraction of the read speeds in flash drives.

it is not 8 Mb/s ... it's 67 Mb/s ... btw, 8 mb means 8 milli bits ... please use the correct terms

Further to Most usb keys have absolutely awful write speeds - in my experience, Toshiba devices are amongst the worst in this respect

Your motherboard also has 6 USB 2.0 ports, so make sure you're using one of the 3.1 ports. As mentioned above, write speeds are often much lower then read speeds and more things come into play. Copying 1 big file will be faster then copying 1 milliion tiny files for example
